# Count records from datatable or array which exist between values in another datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 columns in a datatable, column 1 is the start position of a product and column 2 is the end position. I am trying to count each point accross the datatable that exists between the start point and end point. See the attached image which has the records going downwards.
The row at the bottom is the result of a standard `GroupBy` which is easy, but does not give the required result, the row below "Actual Required" is what I am trying to achieve.
I hope this is clear as I have been unable to get this to work myself, and have found nothing on any site which can give me a similar example to enable me to understand how to do this without looping through each record which is very slow.

[image]

A standard Linq `GroupBy` query is not suitable as it will only count the start and end points, not the values in between. Typicaly the dataset is several thousand records and hundreds of points accross.

Thanks in advance.

```
int[] arr = new int[500];
for(int s = 0;s<arr.Length;s++)
{
    arr[s] = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(r => r.Field<int>("Start") <= s && r.Field<int>("End") >= s)
               .Count();
};
```

Comment: Look at the DataTable.Compute() method.

Comment: Not sure if I missunderstand your comment, but I still need to loop throught each record which is still very slow.  eg arr[s] = (int)dt.Compute("Count(Start)","Start <= "+s+" && End >= "+s); If there is another method please let me know. Thanks for your feedback.